Передать в BackgroundService параметр
Есть BackgroundService.
Как передать в него int-овый параметр?
Т.е. в Setup файле получаю из appsettings переменную и хочу её передать сервису при регистрации.
public class TestService : BackgroundSerice
{
   private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider; 
 
   // Нужно передать someValue при регистрации сервиса
   public TestService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, int someValue)
   {
       _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
   }

   //...
}

Обычная регистрация выполняется так (если не надо передавать someValue):
builder.Services.AddHostedService<TestService>();


Лучше через DI контейнер какой-нибудь передать.

Не совсем понимаю как. Можете привести пример?

.AddHostedService(service => new TestService(service.GetService<IServiceProvider >(), 10000)); (код с головы, поправите сами под реалии). Ну или как сказали выше, через DI, создайте класс с настройками, зарегистрируйте, ну и в сервисе попросите.

Допустим, у нас есть такой сервис:
public class TestService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, int value) : IHostedService
{
    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken);
        }
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

Наша задача передать в него int value, вопрос.. Как?
Вариантов несколько:

Передать это значение при регистрации, сделав что-то такое:
builder.Services.AddHostedService(serviceProvider=> new TestService(serviceProvider, 1000));

Тут мы регистрируем не тип, который будет за нас создан, а уже полноценный экземпляр класса, который мы заполняем самостоятельно нужными данными.
Для красоты, можем сделать свой метод расширения:
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddTestService(this IServiceCollection services, int value)
    {
        services.AddHostedService(ServiceProvider => new TestService(ServiceProvider, value);
        return services;
    } 
}

Тогда регистрация будет простой builder.Services.AddTestService(1000);. Если настроек много, то передавайте Action<>, тогда будет стандартное AddTestService (options => { options.Value = ...; })

Мы можем сделать класс, который будет хранить в себе нужные данные и запрашивать через DI уже его. Один из вариантов пусть будет таким:
public class TestServiceSettings
{
    public int Value { get; set; } = 1000;
}

В сервисе запрашиваем этот класс:
public class TestService(..., TestServiceSettings settings) : IHostedService
{
    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ...
            Console.WriteLine(settings.Value);
        ...
    }

    ...
}

Ну и регистрация пусть будет такой:
builder.Services.AddScoped<TestServiceSettings>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<TestService>();

Все, дальше за нас все инициализирует и внедрит DI контейнер. Пример конечно так себе, но на деле класс с настройками может работать так, как вам надо, хоть получайте настройки с сервера.

Раз уж затронули настройки, то можно использовать тогда и их.

Создаем файл с нужными настройками, допустим, пусть это будет config.json:
 {
   "TestServiceOptions": {
     "SomeInt": 101
   }
 }


Регистрируем его:
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("config.json");


Дальше используем в сервисе, пробросив туда зависимость IConfiguration configuration, ну и в нужном месте читаем нужную настройку configuration["TestServiceOptions:SomeInt"].

Если нам надо, чтоб данные динамично менялись при изменении настроек в файле, то при регистрации конфигурации устанавливаем reloadOnChange (.AddJsonFile("config.json", true, reloadOnChange: true)).

Ну а для удобства работы со всем этим, применяем паттерн настроек (IOptions):

Создаем класс, который будет соответствовать настройкам:
 public class TestServiceOptions
 {
     public int SomeInt { get; set; }
 }


Настраиваем IOptions после регистрации файла:
 builder.Services.Configure<TestServiceOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(TestServiceOptions)));


Применяем в сервисе, пробросив туда IOptions<TestServiceOptions> options и в нужном месте options.Value.SomeInt.

Но тут учтите, с автоматическим обновлением значения из файла нужно будет повозиться немного, это уже оставлю вам.






Собственно, вот вам 3 разных подхода, берите любой и используйте. Тут конечно есть еще варианты, но это по сути основные.

ваш третий вариант это то, что я использую, но я мой класс TestServiceOptions-в вашем примере-MyClassValue, я добавляю в статический для удобства использования отовсюду из проекта string someValue = ApplicationServicesSettings.MyClassValue.SomeValue;

@Dev18 Я вам уже сказал все про статичность. Я против данного подхода. Не будет ее, я бы вам и слова не сказал, да и наверно ответа данного не было. Другими словами, ваша статика - зло, костыль ради удобства. "Доступно везде" - это не всегда хорошо.

приведите пожалуйста пример по третьему варианту, как можно вызвать из сервиса или другого класса переменную из аппсеттингс, то есть оттуда, где  builder. не доступен

вот тестовый проект https://github.com/Dev18000/ExampleAppsettings/blob/master/ExampleAppsettings/Pages/Index.razor

@Dev18 В ответе есть все примеры. Если речь сейчас про Razor страницы, то они также поддерживают внедрения зависимостей. Внедряйте любым удобным способом IConfiguration или IOptions и выводите нужные настройки.

вроде я все подогнала-исправила как показывают, но не работает https://i.sstatic.net/Z4toUYmS.png  //а так работает https://i.sstatic.net/pKecFZfg.png

@Dev18 Так у вас nameof(MyClassValue) выдаст "MyClassValue", когда как в JSON (если брать тот, что в GIT) у вас секция зовется MySettings. Если это не так и вы хотите разобраться - давайте полный код, не скринами.

ыыы, работает, ок, тогда без половника будем ходить https://github.com/Dev18000/ExampleAppsettings/tree/EvgeniyExampleWithoutStatic , я ветку в честь вас назвала

Если я правильно понимаю, то вот так можно. Я использую статический сервис с настройками appsettings
{
  "MySettings": {
    "SomeValue": 42 //наше int-овое значение
  }
}

namespace VashProject.AppSettings
{
    public static class ApplicationServicesSettings
    {
        public const string MySettings = "MySettings";
        public static MyClassValue MyClassValue { get; set; } = new MyClassValue();
    }

    public class MyClassValue
    {
        public int SomeValue { get; set; }
    }
}

Program
builder.Configuration.GetSection(ApplicationServicesSettings.MySettings)
       .Bind(ApplicationServicesSettings.MyClassValue);

builder.Services.AddHostedService(serviceProvider => 
    new TestService(serviceProvider, ApplicationServicesSettings.MyClassValue.SomeValue));


Статичные настройки, сурово...

@EvgeniyZ, получаю из appsettings переменную => это и есть статические данные

В коде должно быть как можно меньше static, ибо подобным вы как минимум постоянно заставляете в памяти висеть ненужные объекты. Ну вот сервис допустим отработал, получил из настроек значение 10, вам нужны потом все эти статичные данные в памяти? Нет конечно... Почему тогда они статичны? Ну возьмите в руку половник и живите с ним вечно, спите, ешьте, мойтесь, гуляйте. Сейчас что-то такое вы делаете в коде. И да, appsettings - это не статичные данные, ведь IConfiguration позволяет считывать эти данные в реал. тайме (изменили файл, без перезапуска данные обновились и в программе).

Почитайте про IOptions, ведь есть вполне адекватные решения (особенно если вы затронули Configuration), которые избавят от статики, а также избавят от new TestService, ведь если использовать настройки правильно, то достаточно в конструкторе TestService попросить нужные настройки (public TestService(...., IOptions<TestServiceOptions> options)). Так что, повторю, это весьма "суровое" решение. P.S. Минус если что не мой.

@EvgeniyZ, призываю вас ответить, так и наглядней и ясней будет, а то ваши комментарии в виде книг уже печатать можно. Прошу, отвечайте

@EvgeniyZ, изменили файл, без перезапуска => я не понимаю, можно на примере.?
